# Какого рода ласси? Кавычить ли пиво и ром?

Tags: пунктуация

> Что ещё важно – здесь подают нежнейш**ие** ласси, и пиво Kingfisher, и
>   даже ром Old monk!

Может, латиница играет свою роль (в смысле быть или не быть кавычкам)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кавычкам-то точно не быть (латиница играет роль; по крайней мере, *"Зенит"* точно кавычится, а *Real Madrid* точно нет). Про *ласси* не скажу.

Comment: С лассями я разобралась: мужескаго, нежнейшия - потому что мн. ч.

Comment: Ежели мужескаго, то должно быть нежнейшиЕ, нет?

Comment: Ние, есть онлайн-перевод на старорежимный! ))) Кто будет проверять?

Comment: Добралась проверить: ты прав! 8-(